# add callback function to underscorejs _.invoke

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm using _.invoke() of Underscore.js to destroy a collection, here is the code:

```
 _.invoke(Labels.selectedItems(), 'destroy', {
   error : function (model, response, options) {
     self.isFailed = true; // initialized with false
     utilities.activateNotification("error", "Deleting label failed", response);
   }
 });
```

How can I add a callback function (or other mechanisms?) to check the value of isFailed after all the destroy functions are finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would be better off looking at promises to solve this problem.

However here's an underscore solution which makes use of the [**after**](http://underscorejs.org/#after) function:

```
// function will be called after it has been called as many times as there are items
var allDone = _.after(Labels.selectedItems().length, function(){
    console.log('The end');
})

// sample destroy function which calls allDone
var destroy = function(params){
    ....
    allDone();
}
```